# Button doesn't change its shape in selector

Tags: android, xml, button, selector, shapes

I'm trying customize outlook of my button.
The problem is, that button doesn't want to change its shape. That mean it's still sharp instead oval.

**button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green_bright">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/green_primary"/>
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/green_primary"/>
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**my_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
<Button android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLVED**

problem was that I declarated *drawable* inside *item*

```
<item android:drawable="@color/..."/>
```

which set fixed background, it makes background unchangeable, so no shape could change button properties. The backgroud color is setted in .

```
<solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
```

**Important!** You can use drawable instead of color, but than **all** your solid colors need to be drawable

```
<solid android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
```

Corrected button_selector.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/blue_bright"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/blue_primary"
                android:width="2dp"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/blue"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="20dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/blue_primary"
                android:width="2dp"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

It is also revelant that you can use your picture inside Button than just put it in:

```
<Button>
  ...
  android:src="@drawable/myPicture"
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use solid to fill color and add width to stroke.
Something like this:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ff22cc84"/>
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff800424"/>
        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Nothing changed. So.. background colors works fine, but shape remained the same. 
I've added  `<shape android:shape:rectangle>` but that has changed anything. I do not even guess where the silver bullet can be.

Comment: What do you mean by shape remains same (no rounded corners)?

Increase the radius to higher value, say 20dp.

<corners android:radius="20dp" />

Comment: I meant shape remains sharp/rectangular. Increasing radius didn't work. Do you think that error is somewhere outside of _@drawable/button_selector_?